# Pyinstaller - Splash screen PNG (transparent) gives pink border

Tags: python, png, pyinstaller

I've successfully created an exe from my python script, including a splash screen using the built in pyinstaller feature (splash).

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
import pyi_splash
pyi_splash.close()
```

Everything works great, except that the transparent PNG that is my splash image gets a tiny pink border around it. A JPG with a background does not. Has anyone encountered this and know of a way to fix it? The PNG is exported from figma. Does it have to be "pixel perfect" to not get the border? It seems like some straight lines get less pink borders than curves and angles.

Snap of the splash screen when run from the exe shown below:

[image: PNG with pink border]

Comment: if i stare at the image long enough the pink lines go away without the need for code...